# conditionally filter results determined by the value of a variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a situation where 2 variables are passed into a query from an external system.

If the variable is 0, then that means don't filter with it.

So something like this:

```
--if @a = 0 then don't filter by @a
--if @b = 0 then don't filter by @b

SELECT * FROM Engines e
JOIN Transmissions t ON e.carId = t.carId
WHERE e.engineId IN(@a)
AND t.transmissionId IN (@b)
```

So, for example, if @a was 0, then only worry about filtering the transmissions. And the query would essentially be:

```
SELECT * FROM Engines e
JOIN Transmissions t ON e.carId = t.carId
WHERE t.transmissionId IN (@b)
```

Or if @b was 0 then it would like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Engines e
JOIN Transmissions t ON e.carId = t.carId
WHERE e.engineId IN(@a)
```

Or if both @a and @b were 0, then show everything like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblA a
JOIN tblB b ON a.carId = b.carId
```

Is there a way to conditionally filter like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASSUMPTION: both @a and @b have defaults of 0.

This should do it:

```
--if @a = 0 then don't filter by @a
--if @b = 0 then don't filter by @b

SELECT * FROM Engines e
JOIN Transmissions t ON e.carId = t.carId
WHERE (@a = 0 OR e.engineId IN(@a))
      AND (@b = 0 OR t.transmissionId IN (@b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Engines
    (
      engineId INT
    , EngineName CHAR(5)
    , carId INT
    );
CREATE TABLE #Transmissions
    (
      transmissionId INT
    , Transmitter CHAR(5)
    , carId INT
    );
INSERT  INTO #Engines
        ( engineId, EngineName, carId )
VALUES  ( 0, 'a', 10 ),
        ( 1, 'b', 20 ),
        ( 2, 'c', 30 ),
        ( 3, 'd', 40 ),
        ( 4, 'e', 50 );

INSERT  INTO #Transmissions
        ( transmissionId, Transmitter, carId )
VALUES  ( 0, 'aa', 10 ),
        ( 1, 'bb', 20 ),
        ( 2, 'cc', 30 ),
        ( 3, 'dd', 40 ),
        ( 4, 'ee', 60 );

DECLARE @a INT= 4
  , @b INT= 0;

DECLARE @where VARCHAR(MAX)
  , @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @where = ( SELECT   CASE WHEN @a = 0
                                  AND @b <> 0
                             THEN '1=1 and t.transmissionId IN ( @b )'
                             WHEN @b = 0
                                  AND @a <> 0
                             THEN '1=1 and e.engineId IN ( @a )'
                             ELSE '1=1'
                        END
             );
--SELECT  @where;
SET @sql = 'SELECT  e.engineId
      , e.EngineName
      , e.carId
      , t.transmissionId
      , t.Transmitter
      , t.carId
FROM    #Engines e
        JOIN #Transmissions t
        ON e.carId = t.carId
WHERE ';
--SELECT  @sql;
DECLARE @FinalSql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DECLARE @a INT=3
  , @b INT= 0; ' + @sql + @where;
--SELECT  @FinalSql;
--SELECT  @FinalSql;
EXECUTE(@FinalSql);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will definitely help you**

```
SELECT * FROM Engines e
JOIN Transmissions t    ON  e.carId = t.carId
WHERE
e.engineId IN @a or isnull(@a,0)= 0)
AND
t.transmissionId IN @b or isnull(@b,0)= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Pankaj Kumar: It works, but there is a syntax error in your code. I can't add a comment so adding it as an other answer:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Engines e
        JOIN Transmissions t
        ON e.carId = t.carId
WHERE   ( e.engineId IN ( @a )
          OR ISNULL(@a, 0) = 0
        )
        AND ( t.transmissionId IN ( @b )
              OR ISNULL(@b, 0) = 0
            );
```